# Set Different titles for global footer variables in Dynamic Jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Can we set different titles for global footer variables?

I have a requirement to display footer variables as below:

---

Total Days : 120 Average Days : 20 Remaining Days : 5

---

Currently I am only able to set one title for all the variables.

I have added 3 Global Footer Variables

```
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(daysColumn,DJCalculation.SUM,style).addGlobalFooterVariable(daysColumn, DJCalculation.AVERAGE,style)
```

The 3rd footer variable should be a Custom Expression that calculates the remaining days.This should be displayed at the end of the Report as

Total Days :120 Avg Days :20 Remaining Days :5

Currently I am able to set only one title by using

```
.setGrandTotalLegend("Total Days")
```

Please help me with displaying different headings for global variables and also how a custom expression can be associated with global variables.

Comment: Provide more details. What is your code doing? How are you getting the titles? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know how to add different titles but .setGrandTotalLegend("Total Days")
works for me as I was seraching for adding one title.